# My wife will be angry, unless I'm home by 7.00

Tags: conjunctions

> My wife will be angry, unless I'm home by 7.00.

In the sentence above the "unless" should not be used. The correct conjunction is supposed to be the "if". Compare this sentence:

> I'll come at 5 unless there is a traffic jam.

Here "unless" is appropriate. Why is it not so in my example sentence?

Comment: Why do you believe you shouldn't use 'unless' in that sentence?  It looks perfectly OK to me.  Using 'if' would give it a different meaning, unless you add the word 'not'.  "My wife will be angry, if I'm not home by 7.00."

Comment: In Practical English Usage by M. Swan this is the example of a mistake that make even very advanced students. Unfortunatelly, I do not have at disposal the full text of Swan so I do not know the explanation.

Comment: I used to use PEU often enough that I have reasons to believe that his book has a couple of flaws, and this is one of them. (This point, iirc, has been mentioned once or twice on ELL, if someone will try until they find it, it will be great.) It's not that his grammar point is invalid, but it's an unfortunate example. Another example is clearer: *\*I'll be surprised unless the car breaks down soon.*, which doesn't work with *unless*, but with *if ... not*, it works. In the *wife* example, I believe that Swan's *wife* is quite ideal. She's never been angry unless the husband is late.

Comment: But these days, I think it's not difficult to imagine a wife who is always angry at her husband, and the only way to better her mood is that the husband must arrive home in or on time.

Comment: I think the original sentence would look a bit better the other way around.  "Unless I'm home by 7.00, my wife will be angry."  I couldn't say why though.

Comment: @DamkerngT. If the car is in terrible shape and I'm expecting it to die at any moment, I might well say "I'll be surprised unless this car breaks down soon."  Okay, I'd be more likely to say "I'll be surprised if this car doesn't break down soon", but I think the sentence is valid with "unless". It may or may not be the intended meaning.

Comment: Your use a decimal point instead of a colon for time is weird; it makes it look like metric time not English time. One normally writes that as one of *“unless I’m home by seven (o’clock)* with actual English words properly spelt out using letters, or *“unless I’m home by 7:00”* with a colon, or *“unless I’m home by 7ᴘᴍ”* with an ᴀᴍ/ᴘᴍ spec. If you can use small caps for *“7ᴘᴍ”*, you definitely should.

Answer (score 8):

The reason that one of these examples is better than the other is not about grammar, it is about *implications*.

An implication is an idea that you might give to somebody, but that you didn't actually properly say. For example, if you say *Give me my book back or I'll punch you*, you are ***saying*** that you will punch the person if they do not give you back your book. But you are only ***implying*** that you will *not* punch the person if they *do* give your book back. But notice that you did not actually say this at all. Maybe you will punch them if they don't give it back and you will punch them if they do!

When we use the word *if* we often give people the idea that the situation in the main clause will be *caused* by the situation in the *if*-phrase:

- It will break if you sit on it.

When we hear the sentence above, we understand something like:

- If you sit on, it it will break *because* you sit on it.

Notice that that is just an implication. We did not actually say that!

When we use the word *unless*, we often give a different implication. Consider this sentence:

- I play outdoor badminton on Tuesdays, unless it's cold outside.

In the sentence above, I am implying that the *normal* situation is that I play badminton on Tuesdays. I am implying that the situation you should expect is that I play badminton on Tuesdays. And I am also implying that somehow "it's  cold outside" is an *exception*. It isn't what you would expect to happen. For this reason it would be very strange for me to say *I play badminton on Tuesdays unless it's cold outside* if I lived in the Arctic!

**Getting it wrong**

Implications are not usually accidents. People use implications to give people extra information without needing to use more words. If we want to show that some situation will *cause* another situation, it is better to use *if* than *unless*. Remember that chair sentence? Well if we use *unless* the sentence will sound very strange:

- That chair will break unless you don't sit on it.

Now, if we are saying this to someone who is thinking about sitting down on a chair, this is a bit odd. This doesn't give the same implications as the *if*-sentence at all. It presents the chair breaking as something we might *expect* to happen, and it makes our not sitting on it sound like an unusual exception. The other reason it is odd is because if we wanted to imply that sitting on the chair would break it, we could just use the word *if* instead! It would be clear and effective. There is nothing wrong with the grammar in the *unless*-sentence. It just presents the information in a strange way, and doesn't use the implications of *if* or *unless* effectively.

It's important to remember that *if* and *unless* do not give opposite implications. They just give different ones. There are many situations where we could use either word and the implications would be useful.

Another thing to remember is that implications are very context-dependent. When the situation we use them in changes, the implications often change too. Also, the way that we arrange information in a sentence can give also different implications. This can change the types of implication that individual words would otherwise have.

**The Original Posters examples**

> 1. I'll come at 5 unless there is a traffic jam.
> 2. My wife will be angry, unless I'm home by 7.00.

The first example gives the implication that the listener should interpret the traffic jam as an exception to what is expected. The second example is not ungrammatical or untruthful. But if the speaker wants to say that not getting home by 7.00 will *cause* his wife to be angry it might be more effective to say:

- If I get home after 7.00, my wife will be angry.

This is not the best example that Michael Swan  could have given. But this is what he means.

Comment: I wonder if the "correct" answer is actually to use 'if...not' instead of just if. _My wife will be angry if I'm not home by 7._ (correct) _My wife will be angry unless I'm home by 7._ (not correct) _My wife won't be angry, unless I'm late._ (correct). I know that colloquially, it is OK to say "Dad will get angry unless I get home by my curfew." but it really isn't 100% correct.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, that would certainly work too, and might be best. I don't think the others are wrong, but they're weird!

Comment: I meant that the comment in the question 'The correct conjunction is supposed to be the "if"' (according to PEU) may be a little misleading because the 'not' is missing - I don't have access to the full text, so I can't say what Swan meant exactly. It isn't a great example sentence regardless.

Comment: So, you mean that these two mean different things? 1 I play outdoor badminton on Tuesdays, unless it's cold outside. 2 I play outdoor badminton on Tuesdays, if it's not cold outside.

Comment: @user1425 It's context dependent, Often there's little to choose between the two. However, if it's nearly always freezing outside there, then your first example would be infelicitous but your second would be ok. The truth conditions are the same, but the implications are different.

Answer (score 4):

> My wife will be angry unless I'm home by 7
>
> If I'm not home by 7, my wife will be angry

In some ways, these two sentences are equivalent. They mean that if you get home at 7:05, your wife will be angry.

*However*, there's a difference in the detail.

> If I'm not home by 7, my wife will be angry

This assumes that your wife is not angry, and will only become angry if you are late.

> My wife will be angry unless I'm home by 7

This assumes that your wife will be angry, and the only way to placate her is to arrive home early.

It's a fairly subtle distinction, and frankly I think your book is being over-zealous as any native speaker would understand the intended meaning without issue.

---

To transfer this to your other sentence

> I'll be home by 5pm, unless there is a traffic jam

As above, the assumption is that you will be home at 5pm.

Again, "unless" gives the assumption that the former clause is *always* true with the *exception* of the situation in the second clause.

> I will be home late if there is a traffic jam

Now the assumption is that the first phrase is only true if the second is also true.

In this example, both are relevant because the initial position is that you are home on time, not that your wife is angry.

The "wrong" version of this sentence would be something more like the following, which perhaps shows why it is wrong.

> I will be home late unless I get home on time.