# Comma usage before relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, commas, restrictive-clauses

> Large machine like clocks which tell the time was invented.

If I want **which** refer to **large machine**, will I need to add comma before **which** ?

Comment: You may want to have a look on this post: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67800/the-use-or-omission-of-commas-round-relative-clauses/67811#67811

Comment: I think it should be "Large machine-like clocks which tell the time *were* invented".

Answer (score 3):

I think that should be "large machine**s**." About the use of comma before the relative pronoun "which," the rule is that if the relative clause is not necessary and is just giving more information about the noun, the comma must precede it; otherwise, the comma must not precede it. Consider the following examples:

> 1. Les Misérables, which was first published in 1862, is a great novel.
> 2. The book which I was reading last night was very interesting

In the first sentence, the book Les Misérables is completely known; therefore, the clause after it is not necessary, but we have used it to give extra information about the the book; thus, you should put a comma before it.

On the other hand, in the second sentence, the listener does not know which book the speaker is talking about, so the comma must not precede it.

Comment: You should work your conclusion "large machine**s**" into the example in the question. I don't think it will work.

Comment: The auxiliary verb should also be changed to "were." Another correction could be the sentence *A large machine like clocks which tells the time was invented*.