# How to describe a noun standing before the last word with 'which'?

Tags: relative-pronouns, ambiguity

I have a sentence:
"I lived in the southern city of Kazakhstan, which is surrounded by mountains."

In this sentence, it looks like that is Kazakhstan is surrounded by mountains. However, I wanted to say that is the city is surrounded by mountains.

How to avoid confusion?

Comment: The simplest way would be to give the name of the city!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The use or omission of commas round relative clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67800/the-use-or-omission-of-commas-round-relative-clauses)

Comment: In practice, your example context is "weird", because ***the** southern city of Kazakhstan* implies either that there's only one city in South Kazakhstan, OR that only one city in that region is surrounded by mountains (and I assume *neither* of those is true). Change it to ***a*** rather than ***the** [city]*, then it's just a matter of whether there's a comma/pause before ***which*** or not. If the comma/pause ***is*** present, ***which*** non-restrictively refers to ***Kazakhstan*** being thus surrounded. If not it restrictively references ***a particular Southern city*** that's surrounded.

Answer (score 0):

I lived in one of the (south's cities/ the southern cities), which is surrounded by mountains, of Kazakhstan.
it is called "Non-defining relative clauses"

https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/non-defining-relative-clauses/